# saving driving directions polyline lat and lon google maps for route geofence

Tags: javascript, php, maps

Assuming you have two points on the map, A and B. 
I get the driving direction of the polyline google maps drawn from A to B. 
Is there any way that I can save the information of the polyline in a database to use it for a route geofence?